# real vertex count addon

Tags: scripting, add-on, vertices

Are there any addons to get the REAL vertex count? e.g. if I have flat shading (which is default in blender tho) I will get way more vertices then blender shows on top of the window, and if I have UV seams it will increase even more.

I've found some scripts (not plugins) that count UV vertices, but it's not what I need. I don't know the api of the blender, so I can't write the addon myself in one day, and I have no time to learn.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking as the shading type doesn't effect the amount of vertices. Are you at some point getting more vertices than blender is reporting?

Comment: i'm modeling for unity. and now i'm learning to model objects that have less then 300 verts (for batching in unity), but when blender shows exactly 300 verts, unity shows more then 1600 (if i import normals from blender). but is i recalculate them to be smoothed (or choose smooth shading in blender), i will get 300 verts like is shown in blender.

Comment: but this is without the uv. if i create seams, i will add some more (not very much) verts to this counter, which blender does not count either

Comment: UV seams increase your polycount?

Comment: not a POLY, but VERTEX count

Comment: Drawing meshes on screen is actually done with vertices which all have exactly one normal, UV coordinate pair and color. Yes, vertices of seam and sharp edges have to be split up because they can not have miltuple UVs and normals. At low level, the same is happening than with the edge split mod.

Comment: This is really more of an issue with exporting to Unity or within Unity itself, rather than Blender.

Comment: Actually i've managed to write the addon: https://github.com/curly-brace/Blender-Vertex-Counter ok. i was asked to elaborate. I WROTE THE ADDON. lol. what to say? was learning low level 3d and blender api for 1.5 days. won't post code here, because i'm sure it will be modified more (on github)

Answer (score 2):

## Use Edge Split

Do not use hard shading, always use smooth shading on the whole object and use the edge split modifier instead. You can split edges based on angle or mark edges sharp with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> and *mark sharp* manually. This will make blender report the proper vertex count when no seams are present. Using the script that counts the UV vertices should give the proper vertex count with edge split and seams.

Answer (score 1):

With some help I made my own add-on: [BetterStats](https://github.com/ssnd292/BetterStats) (Github link).

> Adds a new Statistics overlay in Blender for more in-depth mesh data stats.
> It was always a pain for me to explain to other artists why the vertex normal count is more important than just the vertex count. While in Blender you can visually show them, they are hard to track. My own goal was always to have another way to show the total count of them when doing model optimization, and this is where the idea for this addon came from.

Comment: Interesting question.. Once Normals are split, isn't there one-per-face-corner anyway, even if in smoothed regions, they are deemed to be identical?